# How to alias a type used in a class before it is declared?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

I have code similar to this example

```py
import typing

class C():
    def __init__(self, callback: typing.Callable[[C], int]):
        self._callback = callback

    def getCallback() -> typing.Callable[[C], int]:
        return self._callback

class C2():
    def __init__(self, cInstance: C):
        self._cInstance = cInstance

    def f() -> typing.NoReturn:
        self._cInstance.getCallback()(self.cInstance)
```

and I want to add a type alias for `typing.Callable[[C], int]`

However when I try to do this

```py
import typing

CallbackType = typing.Callable[[C], int] # ERROR: C not defined

class C():
    def __init__(self, callback: CallbackType):
        self._callback = callback

    def getCallback() -> CallbackType:
        return self._callback

class C2():
    def __init__(self, cInstance: C):
        self._cInstance = cInstance

    def f() -> typing.NoReturn:
        self._cInstance.getCallback()(self.cInstance)
```

I get the error that `C` was not defined at the time. If I define the CallbackType after `class C`, then CallbackType is not defined in `C`'s `__init__`. In the example the typing is short enough, but in my actual code it's quite complex, which is why I want to add the alias.

Comment: @InSync If you want to answer with that, i shall accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [forward references](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references):

```py
CallbackType = typing.Callable[['C'], int]
```